# Tense agreement for an action in the future and others before it but also in the future?

Tags: tense-agreement

For the example marked in yellow, I want to know the correct tenses that should be used in the second sentence, written in italics.

> I am afraid there will be a lot of false alarms that will render the new tracking system impractical. *I mean, a few times a week the Aireon’s software **will trigger alarms** for airliners that **have just disappeared** in the middle of the ocean when in reality **nothing serious happened**.* Expensive rescue mission will be initiated just to be canceled after a few hours.

Comment: I think the tenses are OK, but I would write "for airliners that *seem to* have just disappeared in the middle of the ocean" so it is clear that the planes are probably OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it as written. Well, there's a *the* that has no business being there, and *disappeared* should be caveated somehow - "disappeared from tracking", or "seem to have just disappeared". The tenses, though, are completely fine.